# What is the default persistence time for a Firebase auth token?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The firebase docs indicate that auth tokens can be persisted locally, and that the expiry date of these tokens can be modified. This is the default behaviour, since you can log into a firebase app and not have to re-log in for quite some time.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Does anyone know what is the default length of time for these local auth tokens to expire? Is it 24 hours? 30 days? Never?

Comment: Firebase auth tokens are JWT. Grab one and decode it. The `iat` field is the issued-at timestamp. `exp` is the expiration timestamp. The difference is the longevity. If you haven’t changed the firebase defaults, that would provide your answer.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I don't think the question is asking about JWT.  It's asking about the time that a user's identity is persisted in web browser local storage.  That (refresh) token would be used to refresh their ID token, which gets sent as a JWT to the backend.  Since the documentation doesn't specify, I'd say it probably lasts forever, until the browser or the user decides to clear that storage.  The JWT itself itself is only good for 1 hour, then the Firebase Auth ID token must be refreshed.

Comment: Doug you may be right.

Comment: I am referring to JWT tokens, apologies for not being explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `LOCAL` persistence (the default on most platforms), the stored credentials data does not expire.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence):

> Indicates that the state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native. **An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state**